# Starting with Flex right now - should I go for Flex 3 (stable) or Flex 4 (beta)?

Tags: apache-flex

I apologize for making my first question not the hard-hitting code-related question I was hoping for, so I apologize if this question is out of bounds of SO:

I'd like to get started with Adobe Flex development. I've seen that there's been a Beta 2 of Flex 4 available since October (with Flex 4 supposedly being "even better!" than Flex 3, naturally), but obviously, most learning material (books, on-line tutorials etc.) available seem to focus on Flex 3.

This makes me a bit unsure about which version to go with in order to get started.

I realize Flex 3 would be the safer bet, but maybe Flex 4 is already stable enough? I would very much appreciate pointers from developers more experienced with the technology.

Thanks,

Hendrik

Comment: Do you have a time frame for your application?

Comment: No, I'm happy to experiment and let things take their time. I simply don't know the grade of maturity Flex 4 has at this point, and I'm trying to avoid unneeded frustration caused by stuff not being stable, complete etc. enough. (I know *nothing* about Flex.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's so much a question of stability but one of market penetration.  As you said most learning resources out there focus on Flex 3.  That said the Adobe Devnet is filling up with new tutorials and resources for Flex 4.

I haven't moved towards Flex 4 because the libraries are targeted latest versions Flash and AIR, and my apps need to be targeted for older versions of the these runtimes.  That and I have all the features I need using the Flex 3 along with FlexUnit, Degrafa, and other third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you think you need any of the new features for your particular application:

- Remote services – autogeneration of
  data models.
- Flash CS4 support
- Event handler autogeneration
- Declarative graphics
- Unit testing, Network monitor

If you don't need any of these, Flex 3 is the clear choice.

http://www.psyked.co.uk/adobe/flex/talking-about-flex-gumbo-new-features.htm

Comment: I will look into each of these, but considering I'm really just starting out, chances are I will be fine without them for the time being. Thanks!

Comment: One more feature of Flex 4 which I look forward to: real CSS selector support. The selector support in Flex 3 is almost non existent. But for learning Flex you probably will do fine with Flex 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have starting with flash builder with the beta 1!!!! It's much better/easier/nicer as Flex Builder... But the important think is u can use the new sdk!!!!

that's much more iportant... because in the new compantents has many change u have in sdk 3 some components what u can't use in sdk 4...

so my result:
use the new flash builder and use the imortant think SDK 4 ;)